# Displaying data one per record in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

hi guys how can I display the data only once not like on my attached screenshot 
I display that data by hovering on the corresponding markers on the map

hi I have updated my code for better look of what I have now

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFpOD.png)

Here is my updated Codes

**HTML**

```
<div id="searchcontainer"></div>
```

My Javascript

```
function displayData(e)
{
  var html = '';
  var html2 = '';
  var notice = '';
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
     dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key
  mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i])
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
html += '<div id="infocontainer">';
html += '<div class="p-image"><img src="src/images/retrofit.png"/></div>';
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + flsSites[index].site_name + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + flsSites[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + flsSites[index].country_name + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';

`html2 += '<div class="rightcontainer" onclick="DisplayProfileCard();">';
html2 += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png"/>';
html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
html2 += '<span class="details">Product Type</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Version / Size</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
html2 += '</div>';
html2 += '</div>';`

if (!document.getElementById('map_tooltip')) {
    tooltipdiv = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "map_tooltip");
    $(document.body).append(tooltipdiv);
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "display": "block", "padding": "5px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "13000",
        "cursor": "default",
        "font-family": "Segoe UI",
        "color": "#707070",
        "font-size": "12px", "pointer-events": "none",
        "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
        "border": "1px solid #707070"
    });
}
else
{
    tooltipdiv = $("#map_tooltip");
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "left": (e.pageX + 5),
        "top": (e.pageY + 5)
    });
    $(tooltipdiv).html(html).show("slow");
    $('#searchcontainer').innerHTML = "";
    //$('#defaulttext').hide();
    $('#searchcontainer').append(html2);
    $('.rightcontainer').eq($(this).index()).addClass('background');
}
```

Comment: hello kyle can you make it in fiddle

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar unfortunately I cannot make it on jsfiddle because of some weird techinical difficulties here in our office its blocked

Comment: @Kyle could you create a snippet since jsfiddle is blocked? Stackoverflow allows you to create code snippets. You can find the button for that in the tool bar of the question editor or for window you can press CTRL + M.

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar remember that question i asked earlier that thing mouseover in div1 then highlight that corresponding item in div2 that question and this question goes hand in hand so in total you mouseover on a marker in the map then it will be displayed in the div2 but instead of highlighting it just displayed again instead of highliting it

Comment: @Kyle if i understand correct when ever i mouseover on div1 corresponded div2 will show from hidden?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar yes that is correct

Comment: You could place the data into an object with something unique to that item and use one container and whatever element you use for the hove to pass the unique `id` to set the container data...

Comment: It's not really clear what's working and what's not. (1) Is the tooltip working, and if If not what's wrong? (2) is the searchcontainer working and if not what's wrong. Don't answer in comments . Amend the question to clarify it in these terms.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 tooltip is working the only problem is the result just like the attached screenshot all I want is to display only one per item if I hover back to the previous Item it would not display again in the bottom but instead it will highlight the first one on top

Comment: I'm confused. The screenshot appears to depict the `html` variable, which goes into `tooltipdiv`, while `html2` goes into `#searchcontainer`. So do you really mean "tooltip is working"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes tooltip is working the result which is displayed in the #searchcontainer is my problem all I want is just change the color of the background of the item 'IF' it is already displayed not by displaying again in the bottom :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a mechanism to allow a hover handler `displayData()` to know whether or not a `.rightcontainer` for the hovered element has been created previously.

The simplest way to do this is to exploit jQuery's `.data()` to keep a reference to each `.rightcontainer` as it is created. Thus, there's something to test next time round.

I have had a good hack at all the code to knock it into better shape, though there's no guarantee I've not introduced errors.

```
function displayData(e) {
    var mapMarkers = $('#mapContainer .e-mapMarker').get(),
        $tooltipDiv = $('#map_tooltip'),
        grandParent = e.target.parentNode.parentNode,
        flsSite = flsSites[mapMarkers.indexOf(grandParent)],
        $searchcontainer = $('#searchcontainer');

    if(!flsSite) return; // probably?

    // Create tooltip if it doesn't already exist.
    if ($tooltipdiv.length === 0) {
        $tooltipdiv = $('<div id="map_tooltip">' +
            '<div id="infocontainer">' +
            '<div class="p-image"><img src="src/images/retrofit.png"/></div>' +
            '<div class="popupdetail">' +
            '<div class="p-name site"> Site Name: <span></span></div>' +
            '<div class="p-name status"> Site Status: <span></span></div>' +
            '<div class="p-name country"> Country: <span></span></div>' +
            '</div></div></div>').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': '13000',
            'padding': '5px',
            'border': '1px solid #707070',
            'cursor': 'default',
            'pointer-events': 'none',
            'font-family': 'Segoe UI',
            'font-size': '12px',
            'color': '#707070',
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        }).appendTo(document.body);
    }

    // Surely, the code below needs to be executed whether the tooltipdiv is freshly created or not, therefore shouldn't be in an else block. 
    $tooltipdiv.find('.site span').text(flsSite.site_name).end()
        .find('.status span').text(flsSite.status).end()
        .find('.country span').text(flsSite.country_name).end()
        .css({ 'left': e.pageX + 5, 'top': e.pageY + 5 })
        .show('slow');

    // If a previously created rightcontainer doesn't exist, then create one and keep a reference to it.
    if(!$(this).data('rightCont')) {
        $(this).data('rightCont', $('<div class="rightcontainer">' +
        '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png"/>' +
        '<div id="imagedetail">' +
        '<span class="details">Product Type</span>' +
        '<span class="details">Version / Size</span>' +
        '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend</span>' +
        '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>' +
        '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>' +
        '</div></div>').on('click', DisplayProfileCard).appendTo($searchcontainer));
    }

    // Unhighlight all rightcontainers and highlight the current one, whether it was made earlier or just now.
    $searchcontainer.find('.rightcontainer').removeClass('background');
    $(this).data('rightCont').addClass('background');
}
```

*tested only for parse errors*

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: where did you get rightCont the one you used in var $rightCont is it a class of a div or id?

Comment: 'rightCont' is an arbitrary name. I have made an error - currently on mobile phone - will correct it when I get back to my desktop machine.

Comment: now its working but it literally displays only 1 record instead of 1 per each record how can I render the other record if possible below the previous one?

Comment: rightContainer divs are only ever appended to `#searchContainer`, never removed. The only thing I can see that would cause them to disappear would be some CSS directive(s).

Answer (score 0):

There is not so much different to show from hidden , adding background color you will see understand this if not let me know i can explain as much as possible i know

```js
$('.first > ul > li').mouseenter(function(){
$('.second > ul > div').eq($(this).index()).addClass('background').removeClass('invisiblediv');
}).mouseleave(function(){
$('.second > ul > div').eq($(this).index()).removeClass('background').addClass('invisiblediv');
})
```

```css
.first,.second{
  display:inline-block;
}
.first > ul > li {
  width:50px;
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.first > ul > li:hover {
  background-color:#ff5722;
}
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
.background{
  background-color:red;
}
.invisiblediv{
  visibility:hidden;
}
img {
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='first'>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class='second'>
<ul>
<div class='invisiblediv'><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"> </div>
<div class='invisiblediv'><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"> </div>
<div class='invisiblediv'><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"> </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there is so many to do it i am using the selecter with adding and removing classes

Comment: @ Munkhdelger Tumenbayar
I tried your code this time but imagine the attached file being highlited all instead of highlight one item at a time 

$('#searchcontainer').append(html2).eq($(this).index()).addClass('background');

Comment: @kyle i edited for img inside div and visible on mouseenter. mouseout will absolutely hide the img

Comment: just an update on my code it does not work like your for example I hover over 1 it highlights and display 1 in my case I hover at number 1 it display and highlight 1 (that is ok) but if I hover at number 2 it display number 2 but it highlights number 1 instead of number2

Comment: @Kyle put all html and js its not working nothing happened

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kylemarc/r4cxp8Le/ 
here is an update sorry about earlier version